# Distribution of random integer over a given range.

Tags: probability, statistics

Lets say I have a range [1, n]. Now m times, I will take an integer at random from this range.
My question is, what the distribution going to be (m >> n). (I am basically making counts how many times each integer was chosen). How to estimate the avg. difference between the most 'popular' element that was chosen and the 'least'.

Answer (score 1):

Each integer in the range is chosen $\frac{m}n+o\left(\frac{m}n\right)$ times, almost surely.

The integers chosen the most and the least often are a uniformly distributed pair $\{a,b\}$ from the range. 
Let $c=\min\{a,b\}$ and $C=\max\{a,b\}$. For every $i$, 
$$
P[C\leqslant i]=\frac{i(i-1)}{n(n-1)},\qquad
P[c\geqslant i]=\frac{(n-i+1)(n-i)}{n(n-1)},
$$
hence
$$
P[c\lt i\lt C]=1-P[C\leqslant i]-P[c\geqslant i]=2\frac{(i-1)(n-i)}{n(n-1)}.
$$
This yields the average difference between $a$ and $b$ since
$$
E[C-c]=1+\sum_iP[c\lt i\lt C]=\frac{n+1}3.
$$